# Euler's totient function and primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm looking for a proof of this conjecture: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4478597/eulers-totient-function-and-primes

$\phi$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $a$ denotes a natural number > 1 and $n$ denotes a natural number multiple of 4. If the remainder of the division of $\phi(a^n-2)+1$ by $n$ is equal to $n-1$ then $\phi(a^n-2)+1$ is always a prime number.

Example with $a=119$ and $n=20$ The remainder of the division of $\phi(119^{20}-2)+1$ by 20 is equal to 19 then $\phi(119^{20}-2)+1$ is prime.

Max Alekseyev in the linked Math Stack Exchange Post studied the conjecture and gave a partial answer.

Comment: It boils down to just $n=4$. If conjecture hols for $n=4$, then it holds for $n$ being any multiple of $4$, since it reduces to $a' := a^{n/4}$ with $n'=4$.

Comment: New answer on Mathematics Stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646213/660